# Converter tuplas de diferentes bancos de dados em um determinado objeto Java

Tags: java, banco-de-dados

Bem pessoal, não sei se o título da minha pergunta está bem correto, se não estiver, alguém edita por favor. Vou explicar qual o meu problema.

Desenvolvi uma ferramenta que checa conflitos entre políticas de controle de acesso em Softwares como trabalho de conclusão de curso. Por exemplo, ele checa se o software tem duas políticas que não podem ser executadas pelo usuário ao mesmo tempo, como por exemplo as duas políticas:

> -> É permitido para o usuário João abrir um formulário.
>
> -> É proibido para o usuário João abrir um formulário.

Com isso a minha ferramenta compara os objetos Java denominados Politica, que tem a segunda estrutura:

> Politica(tipo, organizacao, usuario, ação, objeto, dataInicio,
> dataFim).

Porém eu busco essas políticas em banco de dados, como por exemplo o da minha universidade, que é o DB2.
O que eu preciso fazer e não tenho noção de como fazer é:

> -> Como me conectar ao banco de dados e obter a sua estrutura.
>
> -> Após obter a sua estrutura, definir quais colunas no banco de dados, se referem aos atributos do meu objeto Politica?

Se o uma tabela tem a seguinte estrutura:

ID - Tipo - Aplicação - Ação - Data Validade - Data Inserção - Unidade

Como fazer uma equiparação e dizer que:
Tipo = Tipo, Aplicação = Objeto, Ação = Ação, Data Validade = DataFim e assim por diante...

E obter uma query disso? E como fazer isso mesmo que as tabelas sejam diferentes, que hajam Joins?

Resumindo e tentando explicar novamente: Como fazer qualquer banco de dados que tenha políticas retornar uma Query com os objetos iguais ao meu objeto Política.

Preciso de um norte pra saber pra onde vai e se é possível fazer. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Essa busca e checagem de estrutura precisa ser automatizada? Eu acho que isso iria aumentar demais a complexidade do seu programa.

Comment: Apaguei o outro comentário porque li errado. Da estrutura não necessariamente, por exemplo, se eu olhasse no banco de dados, identifica-se quais campos se equiparavam, e apenas informasse no programa acho que já seria de grande valia. Em forma de texto mesmo, não sei... Pois o que quero fazer, é isentar o usuário de ter que ou fazer tudo na mão, ou de ter que montar a Query na mão.

Answer (score 2):

> Como me conectar ao banco de dados e obter a sua estrutura.

Cada banco de dados possui pelo menos um software cliente para você acessar. Se tem o DB na sua faculdade, peça o acesso e as ferramentas para o mantenedor do serviço.

No lado do Java, todo acesso a bancos tradicionais é feito usando JDBC. A API é a mesma, você só precisa encontrar o *driver* específico para o seu banco.

Para o DB2 da IBM, veja a página *[DB2 JDBC Driver Versions and Downloads](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21363866)*. Dê preferência para a versão 4.0 do JDBC, porque é mais eficiente.

> Após obter a sua estrutura, definir quais colunas no banco de dados, se referem aos atributos do meu objeto Politica?

Quando você está [recuperando dados do banco](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html) após executar a query, você informa o nome do campo e faz o que quiser com o valor. Exemplo:

```
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    while (rs.next()) {
        String valor = rs.getString("NOME_CAMPO");
        ...
    }
```

> E obter uma query disso? E como fazer isso mesmo que as tabelas sejam diferentes, que hajam Joins?

Basicamente você:

1. Faz uma query diferente para cada tipo de banco que você quer.
2. Para cada query você recupera os valores em variáveis, assim como no exemplo acima.
3. Com essas variáveis, você então cria uma instância da sua classe `Politica` passando os valores conforme achar adequado e colocando nos atributos da classe.

Uma vez que você tiver todos os dados numa lista uniforme de objetos do tipo `Politica`, então você pode criar um método para percorrer essa lista e detectar conflitos fazendo comparações simples nos atributos desses objetos.

Note que há várias outras formas de resolver o problema, mas tentei sintetizar uma maneira simples e direta, sem sofisticações técnicas.

Comment: Fala @utluiz, muito obrigado pela resposta. Essa parte do JDBC realmente me ajuda muito, e acho que pode ser dessa forma mesmo. Porém, eu queria abstrair do usuário ter que ter o gerenciador de banco de dados pra visualizar a estrutura do banco, não teria um comando SQL ou algo do tipo para que eu exibisse isso para ele na ferramenta? Obrigado!

Comment: @JoãoNeto Não é fácil fazer um sistema que permite ao usuário digitar qualquer tipo de consulta. Entretanto, é possível através da API [`DatabaseMetaData`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html). Veja exemplos de como usá-la: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/databasemetadata.html

Comment: @JoãoNeto Você pode até criar um "query wizard" para que o usuário consiga montar consultas através de uma interface visual e aí você armazena a consulta criada e executa ela posteriormente. Entretanto, a complexidade de fazer isto é muito alta e eu diria que você iria acabar não entregando seu TCC. Se concentre no que importa: primeiro faça a lógica de detecção de conflitos, depois faça uma implementação que lê isso de um banco qualquer, depois tente fazer algo para deixar a interface mais simples.

Comment: no caso eu já terminei a ferramenta e ela já está funcional, vou apresentar dessa forma entende? Só que minha professora pediu uma ajuda pra continuar esse desenvolvimento, ai agora já não tenho mais tanta restrição com tempo, tenho alguns meses para desenvolver só isso. Então isso poderia ser uma opção, a query wizard, vou dar uma pesquisada em como pode ser feito.

Comment: vou dar uma olhada nesta API também. Novamente, obrigado pela disposição!